# Axios.post doen't work in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

i'm using Axios in react js to fetch data from API( which i created with .NET WEB API  ) 
The Axios.Get worked perfectly for me , now i'm trying to use Axios.Post to Add Data In My DataBase Via My API ( http://localhost:51492/api/experience ) 
but i'm getting in  the backend project an error :

> SqlException : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_experiences_users_UserID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "master", table "dbo.users", column 'Id'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

and this error appear when i continue running my backend project after getting the previous error : ( error shown in google dev tools )

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) profile:1 Failed to load
>   http://localhost:51492/api/experience: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
>
> createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87) createError @ createError.js:16 handleError @ xhr.js:87

this is my code in react js using axios.post :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
 var nowDate = new Date();
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    titre: '',
    contenu: ''
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ titre: event.target.value,  contenu: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const exp = {
      titre: this.state.titre,
      contenu: this.state.contenu,
      datePub:  nowDate ,
      userID: 1
    };

    axios.post(`http://localhost:51492/api/experience`, { exp })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
       })


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            titre:
            <input type="text" name="titre" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label>
            contenu:
            <input type="text" name="contenu" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>

          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Please can someone help me  ? thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have enabled CORS on server side for development purpose.

Try this way to set header and send a post request:

```
const URL = `http://localhost:51492/api/experience`;

 return axios(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: exp,
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
```

Let me know if the issue still persists ! Happy to help

Comment: Thank u very much that made it work , the Cors was already enabled

Comment: Glad to hear this.

Comment: I have added header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on top of PHP file. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS in the server (it basically allows every XHR instance to request data from it. There are plenty resources online on how to enable CORS on ASP.NET. If you do not own the server please consider using fetch instead of axios.